# How to fix a warning "Non COM-visible value type is being referenced either from the type currently being exported or from one of its base types"?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, com, activex

I develop an ActiveX Component. It inherits from System.Windows.Forms.UserControl.

When I build my project in Visual Studio, then I get 0 errors and about 20 warnings looks like the following sample:
"warning : Type library exporter warning processing 'ActiveXControl.ActiveXControl.get_Anchor(#0), ActiveXControl'. Warning: Non COM visible value type 'System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles' is being referenced either from the type currently being exported or from one of its base types."

I have tried to google a solution to fix these warnings, but I can't find anything that helps me.

Any idea how can I fix these warnings?

Comment: Well, you are doing it wrong.  You complain about the members that the type library exporter *know* that are not usable, but there are many, many more.  We can't see what you did, but you probably used the [ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.AutoDual)] attribute on the class.  That is the easy way, but not the ideal way by a long stretch.  Write a [ComVisible] interface that only exposes properties and methods that you want the client code to use.  Implement it in the UserControl class.  Now you can use ClassInterfaceType.None

Comment: Hans Passant, you was absolutely right, I use AutoDual in ClassInterface attribute and your solution has fixed all warnings. Thank you. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look an answer in first comment of the post.